# Php best and secure way to submit and process a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

Is this a good practice to set the get request to process a form using the php code at the top of the page like this?

```
<?php
require_once("include/dbconfig.php");
require_once ("include/userCrud .crud.php");
$userCrud = new userCRUD($pdo);
if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
{ 
 //Question Data    
 $name= $_POST['name'];
 $subject_id = $_POST['subject_id'];
//other stuffs like Connecting 

$result = $userCrud->create($name, $subject_id, $address, $is_active, $date_created);
}
?>
```

//And in the center of the page...

```
<form ...>
...
<select name="level_id" id="level_id" class="form-control" title="Please select standard or level" required>
                                                    <option value="">Choose a Level</option>
<?php
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM levels");
  $stmt->execute();
  $data=$stmt->fetchAll();
  if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
  foreach($data as $row) {
?>                                                      
<option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></option>
<?php
  }
  }
?>  
                                                </select>
...
</form>
```

OR
Making an AJAX call via JQuery and updating result without refresh. I was just looking around using PDO in php for my web app... also Should I create my own web services trying to do routing and securing from scratch... OR Should I go for a framework like Slim.. As if I am using the AJAX way of form processing then I will keep calling my json web services...and I need not use database connections in my php page. Also it can be used by mobile apps to use these php classes I will create like....

getUsers.php //returns json array

getSubjects.php // parameter passed by query string for operations

I was just wondering which will be more secure and good...as I have preferred to use PHP for this project.

Comment: Use a framework. Also asking what's more secure is a very broad question because one approach isn't inherently more secure than the other. It depends on how you implement them.

Comment: A secure way to submit a form is using a `POST` request, and some kind of `CSRF` protection, and also `XSS` protection....also your database queries should be parameterized...that is for a start...you should also make sure to disable your root MySQL password, do not store sensitive data on plain text an so on...it's a never ending story :)

Comment: Yes... great suggestion... Hackerman...Can you please suggest on :make sure to disable your root MySQL password

Comment: http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/disable-remote-root-logins-into-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Including php in html may be good when you code small things, when you go bigger it is creating confusion and chaos. I would recommend keeping data manipulation and application logic separate from html. You have much more options than just php in html or ajax calls (google MVC for example, it's standard in creating webpages).

Making your own routing/securing/app structure may be good excersise, but since you're starting your jurney with php it will be hard to do it properly/secure and can be quite demotivational when you get problem after problem. I would recommend trying some framework - when you encounter something you can't handle there is high propability someone already knows how to fix it on stackoverflow or in that framework community.